# jquery .remove not working

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

i was trying to add a hyperlink to a div onClick and i intended that when i clink again the appended hyperlink is removed... everything is working fine onClick the hyperlink is appended to the intended div but they are not being removed...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("[href=#]").click(function() {
            if ($("#appendContainer").is(":parent")) {
                var child = $("#appendContainer").children().attr("id");
                alert(child);
                $('#' + child).remove();

            }

            $("#appendContainer").append(
$("<a/>", { href: "#", id: "helloWorldLink" }).text("Helloworld"));
        });
    });

</script>




    <a href="#">click here</a>
         <div id="appendContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your added link doesn't have your onClick listener.

Try to use .live() to set event handler. Use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("[href=#]").live('click', function() {
            if ($("#appendContainer").is(":parent")) {
                var child = $("#appendContainer").children().attr("id");
                alert(child);
                $('#' + child).detach();
                return;
            }

            $("#appendContainer").append(
              $("<a/>", { href: "#", id: "helloWorldLink" }).text("Helloworld")
            );
        });
});
```

Note, what i've added `return` after the `detach()` to avoid adding new link just after removing old one.

Answer (score 1):

You are always appending the anchor link though you are removing it if already exists. You need to add the else block after if. i.e.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("[href=#]").click(function() {
            if ($("#appendContainer").is(":parent")) {
                var child = $("#appendContainer").children().attr("id");
                alert(child);
                $('#' + child).remove();

            }
           else {
            $("#appendContainer").append($("<a/>", { href: "#", id: "helloWorldLink" }).text("Helloworld"));
          }
        });
    });  </script>
```

Comment: It is not the only reason. New <a> will not get onClick handler.

Comment: @Olegas: I dont think OP is referring to the click of link being added dybamically. If that's the case then link can only be clicked once to hide it. Once it is hidden there is no way to make it visible.

Comment: the question is about a removing of a dynamically added link by clicking on it. Dynamically added link will no get onClick handler setted on links, previously placed on page. Using live() here is necessary. P.S. - what is OP?

Comment: I understand how live works. The confusion here is whether OP is referring to a different link to create the new link and then clicking the newly created link should remove itself. Since the answer is accepted, I guess that was what asked for. OP = Original Poster.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
  function linkClickHandler() {
    var appendContainer = $('#appendContainer');
    appendContainer.children().remove();
    appendContainer.append(
       $('<a/>', {
          href: '#',
          id: 'helloWorldLink',
          click: linkClickHandler,
          text: 'HelloWorld'
       })
    );

    $('[href=#]').click(linkClickHandler);
  }
}
```

Or use live (but it is slower for this case).